# How to height an inline list?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm creating a list menu like this:

> - Some heading at the top `h1`
> - And the list below, with the items of `li`

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oeyvb17g/6/) as demo. Here's my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body>ul {
  text-align: center;
  height: 78px;
}

body>ul>li {
  display: inline;
  background: blue;
  height: 80px;
}

body>ul>li>h1 {
  display: block;
  /* width:100%; */
  background: orange;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="large-list">
    <h1>I WANT 100% WIDTH</h1>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">TRy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TRy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TRy</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is I want the list to have `80px` height (for an example) and I want it below the `h1`.

I've tried `display:inline` instead of `inline-block`, but when it's inline I cannot use `height: 80px` in css.

Can anyone please help me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the H1 out of the list, which is cleaner anyway.

I've remove the `li{display: inline(-block);}`, and removed margin/padding from the ul to make it align left with the header.

```css
body {
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
body > ul {
    text-align:center;
    height:78px;
    background: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body > ul > li {
    background:blue;

  }
  body > h1 {
    background:orange;
    margin: 0;
  }
  a {
    color:white;
  }
```

```html
 <h1>I WANT 100% WIDTH</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">TRy</a></li>
  <li><a href="">TRy</a></li>
  <li><a href="">TRy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach, changing your code as little as possible, would be something like below. Moving `h1` out of the list.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body>h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

body>ul {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 78px;
}

body>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 80px;
}

body>ul>li>h1 {
  display: block;
  /* width:100%; */
  background: orange;
}

a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>I WANT 100% WIDTH</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">TRy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TRy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">TRy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding instead of trying to increase its height. Use below example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin:0;padding:0;
  }
  body > ul {
    text-align:center;
    padding:78px;
  }
  body > ul > li {
    display:inline;
    background:blue;
    height:80px;
  }
  body > ul > li > h1 {
    display:block; /* width:100%; */
    background:orange;
  }
  a {
    color:white;
  }
  .header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="header"><h1>I WANT 100% WIDTH</h1></div>
  <ul>
    <li class="large-list"></li>
    <li><a href="">TRy</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TRy</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TRy</a></li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And use a seperate div to include your header. I recommend you to use bootstrap instead of rough coding everything. Link: http://getbootstrap.com/